# Adding a row to a CSV file using DictWriter in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am using a DictWriter to write to a csv file to a single row, however; only a two columns are being populated. Here are some  code snippets of what I am working on with the focus being on the function *Stat2*():

def scheduledPerformanceAvailability(FILENAME, CATEGORY):

```
# get category column for current entry
entry = retrieveEntries(FILENAME, CATEGORY)

# grab the most frequent entry from the collections.counter 
mostFrequent = entry.most_common(1)[0][1]   
print "\n", mostFrequent;

# calculate the total number of values in the file
totalNumber = sum(entry.values())
print "\n", totalNumber

# caculate the percentage
percentage = float( mostFrequent / totalNumber ) * 100  
print "\n", percentage, "%\n";

return percentage
```

def *Stat2*(FILENAME2, itemValue, percentage):

```
    # store the values into a list
    entry = []

    percent = str(percentage)
    displayPercentage = percent + ' %'

    entry.append({'DEPARTURES_SCHEDULED': displayPercentage, 'UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME':itemValue})

    fieldnames = ['DEPARTURES_SCHEDULED','DEPARTURES_PERFORMED','SEATS', 'UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME']

    # open a file for writing
    outfile = open(FILENAME2, 'a')

    # create the csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)

    # check the file before appending any unecessary headers
    ckfile = open(FILENAME2, 'r').read()

    if(ckfile == ''):
        csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))

    for row in entry:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)

    # close the file
    outfile.close()
```

def most_commonCatgoryO_(FILENAME1, FILENAME2, CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2):

```
# create the field names for each category      
fieldnames = ['DEPARTURES_SCHEDULED','DEPARTURES_PERFORMED','SEATS', CATEGORY1]

# open a file for writing                                                       
outfile = open(FILENAME1,'wb')  

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction = 'ignore')

csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))

entry = retrieveEntries('input/NC_SC Proj Data_2012 {Intermediate-File}.csv', CATEGORY1)    

# grab the item value associated with the most frequent number
itemValue = entry.most_common(1)[0][0]  
# print "\n", itemValue;

# reopen the intermediate for reading
infile = open('input/NC_SC Proj Data_2012 {Intermediate-File}.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.DictReader(infile)

# populate the outfile using the pre-defined condition
for row in reader:
    if(row[CATEGORY1] == itemValue):        
        csvwriter.writerow(row)

outfile.close()

#open the outfile for reading
with open(FILENAME1, 'rb') as infile:

    # calculate the percentage
    percentage = scheduledPerformanceAvailability(FILENAME1, CATEGORY2)
    _Stat2_(FILENAME2, itemValue, percentage)

infile.close()
```

For example, my csv file:

DEPARTURES_SCHEDULED,DEPARTURES_PERFORMED,SEATS,UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME
3.90977443609 %,,,US Airways Inc.
4.21052631579 %,,,US Airways Inc.
1.8045112782 %,,,US Airways Inc.

My desired output should be:

DEPARTURES_SCHEDULED    DEPARTURES_PERFORMED    SEATS   UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME

3 %     4%             1%                               US Airways Inc.

Comment: When I run your code with test data (`percent = "100"` and `itemValue = 10`), I get: `DEPARTURES_SCHEDULED,DEPARTURES_PERFORMED,SEATS,UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME` and `100 %,,,10` Do your values for `itemValue` or `percent` contain newlines?

Comment: I get results similar to beerbajay's. Please update your question and add some sample calls to the function along with actual results. Any resulting csv file will have commas in it separating the values.